# How to provide public read access to a file in s3fs in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I want to provide public read access to file uploaded in folder on s3 amazon server.My code sample is

```
    var s3Options = {
                  accessKeyId: config.bucket_access_key,
                  secretAccessKey: config.bucket_secret_access_key
         };

    var fsImpl = new S3FS(config.bucket_name, s3Options);
    fsImpl.writeFile(fileName, stream).then(function (err,data) {
      //code
    });
```

Comment: What is the npm package that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by adding 'ACL' key -

```
 fsImpl.writeFile(fileName, stream,{ACL: 'public-read'}).then(function (err,data) {  
     // code
 })
```

Hope that helps.